# autonumber in select statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to create a select query statement with autonumber.. like..

```
select * from tbl1
```

will give me everything from table.

The result I'd like to get is..

```
1         data
2         data
3         data
```

So how can I do to get that number..??

like..

```
select (for autonumber), * from tbl1
```

the data in my table will repeated (no unique data)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rn, * FROM tbl1
```

To filter the results based on the row number use this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rn, * FROM tbl1
) T1
WHERE rn = 5
```

Comment: yea.. that's the correct answer.
I would like to do sth like.. SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rn, * FROM tbl1 where rn=5; Apparently it doesn't work like that.. any solution for that?

Comment: @william: You need to generate the row number in a derived table and filter in an outer select. I'll update my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: I may look stupid to ask this question. But wht is T1? And I can't put 'order by' in inner select statement, is that normal?

Comment: @william: T1 is an alias (name) for the derived table. I believe you can only use ORDER BY in a derived table if you have TOP. PS: If you want find the 5th row you can select TOP(5) in the derived table. This will most likely give a performance boost. Currently a full scan is required.

Comment: @william: That alias, T1, can be any name you choose only it is required in this case by T-SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to find the identity's offset e.g. last ID of second table:

```
DECLARE @lastAutoID int 
SET @lastAutoID = abs(( Select max(convert(float,[ConsID])) 
FROM [RXPIPEDB]...[consumption] ) )
```

Then use ROW_NUMBER():

```
@lastAutoID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  oldICN_str)
```